# onDeviceReady funchtion is not working on PhoneGap app

Tags: cordova, geolocation

This is my index.html code here:

```
function onDeviceReady(){  aler ('hi');}
```

It's not working. Could you please suggest a solution.

[image: Html Code]

Comment: In the image, you've commented alert('hi'); so it is not executing. If this is not the answer your looking for, then please edit your question so that is in a more understandable format.

Comment: The problem is that ondeviceready function sometime working and sometime not ,

you can see in the header section i add this script to execute ondeviceready function is it the curract way pls suggest me.

<script>
    function onDeviceReady () {
    // alert("Calling onDeviceReady()");
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    }, 1000);
  </script>

Comment: why you are creating onDeviceReady() function twice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use timeout to register deviceready event. Since this event will be called only once, when all app resources are loaded.
**Your code is trying to register deviceready function twice, which is wrong**. 
When you are trying to register it for second time, it's registering the function which you have define at top. Since the second function is still not in existence. **Plz first edit your code and correct it to remove duplicacy**. Your issue will get easily resolved.

Comment: when i add two function **ondeviceready** then alert works well but when i deleted upper Ondeviceready function alert not working in my code..
please suggest me.

Comment: please paste latest code along with above question.